# Can an n dimensional object cover an n+1 dimensional object?

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

Is it possible for an $n$-dimensional object to ever cover an $(n+1)$-dimensional object? For example, could a square ever cover a cube?

Note: Definition of "cover" here means to completely cover the surface area, while not breaking the dimensionality. For example, a piece of paper could be folded around a cube, but then you'd just have another cube.

Edit for clarification: By "cover," I mean something akin to "wrapping" a 2D object around a 3D object without simply creating a 3D object. One of my "mathy" friends phrased his answer this way:

"Form an $n$-dimensional basis using $n$ orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$; this is space $A$. Form an $(n-1)$-dimensional basis using $n-1$ orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$; this is space $B$. To prove that you can't do what you're saying, prove that there exists a surface in space $A$ that contains points that do not exist in space $B$ (which is trivial)."

By the way, this ISN'T a homework problem, I thought of it lying in bed last night and nobody seems to have an answer.

Comment: See [space filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) for an example of exactly this

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the question he is actually asking, though it is very interesting. He seems confused about dimensionality, conflating the two-dimensional surface of a cube with the full three-dimensional cube. The note seems in direct contradiction to what is said before. Can you clarify, Decker?

Comment: Added clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n = 2$, the answer is yes if one restrict to 3-d objects whose surfaces are formed by connected 2-d polygons.

This is proved in a paper
*Folding Flat Silhouettes and Wrapping polyhedral packages: New Results in Computational Origami* by E. Demaine, M. Demaine and Mitchell around year 2000.

An online copy can be found 
[here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772199000565).

Comment: This led to [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772109000182).